# object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in R MARKDOWN

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to do a coefficient plot for my multiple regression. The code on R works perfectly, and also when running it in Rmarkdown it works and shows my plot. However, when I try to knit the document I see "Error in v[j]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. I have no idea of how to do.

this is my code:

```
mods=list("Model 1"=reg1,"Model 2"=reg2, "Model 3"=reg3, "Model 4" =reg4, "Model 5"=reg5)

var_names <- c('Signal' = 'Mediaset Signal',
               'ShareDiploma' = 'Share of Graduates',
               'Lnincome' = 'Household Income',
               'log(Ruggedness)'='Ruggedness of the Ground',
               'log(Electorate)'='Number of electorate')

coeffplot1 <- modelplot(mods, coef_omit= "Interc",
          vcov="robust",
          coef_map= var_names)+
  labs(title="Forza Italia's Vote Share",
       subtitle = "Graphical representation of the regression's coefficient effects",
       caption= "Robust Standard Errors in Parentheses")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="red", size=0.25)

       

coeffplot1
```

Comment: also, i have the error in line 233, which is empty

Comment: In console it works nice by you? By me - not. Which libraries and data do you use. Add to question, please.

Comment: usually this means you are trying to index something(function or data type) that doesn't support indexing. looks like this is happening at the `v` object in your code that may not be in your specific code example